# Select value via index using watir and ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I have such code:

```
total_terms = @driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').length
    if (1...5).include?(total_terms)
      @driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').option(:index, total_terms).select
    else
      @driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').option(:index, (total_terms-2)).select
    end
```

and I am trying to select some value via index. First, I calculate how long my `select_list` is, and then I select. But in the browser, I see that nothing is selected. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is probably throwing exceptions.

**Select lists do not have a method length**

The line

```
@driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').length
```

is not valid since select lists do not have a method `length`. Assuming you want the number of options, need to add the `options` method to get a collection of options in the select list:

```
@driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').options.length
```

**5 or less options selects non-existent option**

The line

```
if (1...5).include?(total_terms)
  @driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').option(:index, total_terms).select
```

will throw an exception due to there being nothing at the specified index. The :index locator is 0-based - ie 0 means the first option, 1 means the second option, etc. This means that when there are two options, you will try to select :index => 2, which does not exist. You need to subtract 1:

```
if (1...5).include?(total_terms)
  @driver.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$cp$cbRodzajUslugi').option(:index, total_terms-1).select
```